# Detectar F5 o recargar y enviarlo siempre a home. JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Necesito saber si hay alguna manera de identificar cuando un usuario hace una recarga de la página mediante f5 o actualizar en el botón del navegador para programar una acción y que este redirija siempre a la pagina de inicio.

Estoy utilizando un `phase listener` en donde puedo comparar antes de cargar cada pagina el id de la vista y los comparo si son iguales hago una re dirección a la regla de navegación del home.

El problema de este método esta en que no se diferencian cuando hago un actualizar , a cuando se recarga la pagina mediante `Ajax` , por ejemplo en el paginador de una tabla.

¿Hay alguna opción en la cual pueda identificar si la recarga viene desde ajax o si viene desde f5 o botón actualizar del navegador ?

este es el código de el `listener`.
Gracias

```
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PostRedirectGetListener implements PhaseListener {
private String previousPage = null;

public PhaseId getPhaseId() {

    return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
}

public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {

    String msg = "";
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    String id = viewRoot.getViewId();       
    if (previousPage == null) {
        msg = "First page ever";
    } else if (previousPage.equals(id)) {
        msg = "F5 or reload";
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String outcome = "urlHome";
        facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler()
                .handleNavigation(facesContext, null, outcome);
    } else if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        msg = "It's a postback";
    } else
        msg = "It's a navigation";
    previousPage = id;
    System.out.println(msg);
}


public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {

}

}
```

Comment: Un phase listener no servirá puesto que el evento de refrescar se ejecuta de lado del cliente mientras que el listener se ejecuta para eventos de lado del servidor. Debes utilizar alguna manera de detectar el window unload en el lado del cliente y en base a eso lanzar tu acción JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

En tu vista puedes agregar lo siguiente:

```xhtml
<f:metadata>
   <f:viewAction action="#{f5Detector.checkF5}" onPostBack="true"/>
</f:metadata>
```

BackEnd

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class F5Detector {
  private String previousPage = null;

  public void checkF5() {
    String msg = "";
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    String id = viewRoot.getViewId();
    if (previousPage != null && (previousPage.equals(id))) {
       // It's a reload event
    }
    previousPage = id;
  }
}
```

Lo puedes hacer también mediante javascript, ya que al pulsar F5 se activa el evento `event window.onunload()`.

Incluso puedes intentar con .

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; ,URL=http://redirecciona a ...">
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta , he  intentado esto pero me pasa lo mismo el detecta el f5 , pero tambien cuando se hace una recarga ajax por ejemplo abrir un pop up, tambien se detecta como un F5 , no se es como diferenciar el f5 del ajax.